# Что делать, если вопрос вызывает злость?

Tags: обсуждение, faq, вопросы

Когда я вижу некоторые вопросы, меня удивляет, насколько они просты и насколько близко лежит ответ, который мог бы быть обнаружен автором, насколько ужасно они оформлены, насколько нечитаем написанный код. В эти моменты я обычно пишу гневные ответы/комментарии с инструкциями в краткой форме, но ощущаю, что поступаю неправильно.

Как мне правильно поступить?

Comment: "насколько они просты и насколько близко лежит ответ" - на SO полно вопросов типа "как сложить два списка".

Comment: А что делать если ответ вызывает злость? Что делать если модераторы снесли вопрос от просто так (это про остальной stackexchange)? Что если ото дня в день требования к вопросам задираются и задираются? Что делать если ничего не получается?

Comment: @SmitJohnth да в общем-то, все то же самое. Прямое выливание злости ни к чему не приведет, однако, можно попытаться переубедить, против холодных аргументов сложно что-то противопоставить. Если забегать совсем далеко, то в играх и сраных пабликах я срусь только в путь, обличая любителей ставить запятые между подлежащим и сказуемым, но здесь стараюсь сдерживать себя. Ну и если хочется что-то поменять, то надо в первую очередь искать не самые прямые, а самые эффективные пути. Ну и если совсем уж докопаться, то общение в интернете не должно приниматься близко к сердцу.

Comment: Гневные ответы и наезды на спрашивающего раздражают не меньше.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: самый популярный мой ответ отвечает на буквальный вопрос: [Почему нельзя просто взять и сложить два словаря?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431760/23044) (если вопрос простой, это ещё не значит, что не стоит на него отвечать).

Answer (score 41):

На мой взгляд, это очень деликатный вопрос, в котором необходимо настолько же осторожно разобраться.
Я замечаю подобное поведение за собой и максимально стараюсь его нивелировать.
          Я считаю, что на этом сайте нет места ничему подобному: лучше не ответить на вопрос, нежели ответить на него агрессивно.
 Да, действительно, некоторые вещи могут просто вымораживать, но это не значит, что надо вымещать свою злость здесь же — я считаю, что мы несём образовательную функцию, и эта образовательная функция выражается не только в разборе конкретных примеров и пересказе документации.
 Если человек что-то не нашёл в гугле, то  он возможно, *не знает*, как искать. Возможно, он не понимает написанного в статье. Возможно, ему кажется, что он её понял, и ему надо деликатно пояснить, что этого не случилось. Возможно, он не делает учебное задание потому, что не верит, что он с ним может справиться.
Никто не становился специалистом в один день, и всем этим людям, какой бы корявый код у них не был — нужна помощь, и помощь, зачастую, не только непосредственно в объяснении протекающих процессов, но и *мета-помощь*, которую мы можем предоставить, чтобы человек решил не только свою задачу, но и сверхзадачу тоже.
 Да, бывает, что объяснить всё просто нету времени и желания; это мой случай. Но я стараюсь просто проходить мимо, когда не могу ответить, либо оставить короткий комментарий, который, возможно, наведет человека на след. Таким образом, я рекомендую либо не писать ничего вообще, либо писать, как улучшить свой вопрос, почему акцент на тех или иных вещах важен, и т.п.

И тут будет ещё один абзац. 
 Я действительно не хочу, чтобы под вопросами были гневные заметки и чтобы вопросы втихую минусовались без объяснения, но не призываю, конечно, потакать всеми любимым домашним заданиям и выполнять за кого-то работу.
 Я призываю оказывать помощь не только содержанию вопроса — задаче — но и автору в целом — его сверхзадаче стать программистом.
 И вот здесь нужно сделать очень важную заметку, — такие эмоции как агрессия, ненависть и злость являются к сожалению, частью человеческой натуры, и мы не можем полностью от них отказаться, и самое худшее, что может для себя сделать человек — это [запретить отдельные эмоции](http://www.ted.com/talks/brene_brown_on_vulnerability?language=ru). Лично я стараюсь снимать напряжение другими способами, но если вдруг вы чувствуете, что вас перехлестывает через край — возможно, проблема совсем не в вопросах, и с ней надо работать.

Подытоживая: первое, что вы можете сделать, почувствовав жгучее желание объяснить автору, на чём мир стоит — просто закрыть вкладку и пройти мимо. Кроме того, если юзеры-паровозы будут отвечать на все подряд, то для людей среднего уровня просто не будет простора для зарабатывания своего имени. Я действительно вижу проблему в том, что у нас появляется не так много новых лиц, и я уверен, что доброжелательным отношением мы могли бы просто взрастить дополнение к костяку из новичков.
Альтернативный вариант — можно вдохнуть, выдохнуть, и максимально формально, подробно и отстранёно расписать автору, в чем его ошибки. Например:

> XXX, у тебя отсутствует форматирование кода, в результате чего я не могу его прочитать за разумное время.
>   Пожалуйста, приведи его в порядок. Забегая вперед — существует большая вероятность того, что ты не разобрался с асинхронными вызовами в javascript, возможно, тебе просто необходимо прочитать [соответствующую статью](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) в документации ещё раз.

Comment: Отлично. Мне правда понравились и вопрос и особенно ответ. Было бы чудесно, если бы этот текст разместили в прямо [правилах](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @avp: для правил длинновато, вот если бы выжимку на 2-3 строки, тогда ок ;-)

Comment: @KromStern выжимка: "просто закрыть вкладку и пройти мимо." :)

Comment: Больше всего вымораживает то, что на русском SO таких вопросов на 90% больше, чем на обычном SO.

Comment: Добавил ответ новым разделом справки: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-positive

Comment: Согласен с основной идеей, но мне кажется, что было бы очень полезно иметь ссылку, куда можно направлять авторов плохих (неотвечаемых) вопросов, чтобы не разжевывать каждому, что такое тесткейс, и почему на "у меня не работает" иногда сложно ответить. Страничка http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask в этом плане удручает не меньше чем плохие вопросы...

Answer (score 18):

> В эти моменты я обычно пишу гневные ответы/комментарии с инструкциями в краткой форме, но ощущаю, что поступаю неправильно.

конечно, неправильно.

правильное, позитивное восприятие «плохих» вопросов должно быть примерно таким:

*как хорошо, что этот вопрос задали **не мне***.

и следом:

*возьмусь-ка, да помогу тому бедолаге, которому придётся отвечать: приведу вопрос в «человеческий» вид*.

Comment: Гм. *"Долго думал" (с)* Спасибо за идею :)

Answer (score 14):

Люди, которые задают вопрос, хотят получить на него ответ. Необходимость в ответе привела их сюда и заставила 200-300 раз стукнуть по клавиатуре, чтобы задать вопрос. Давайте использовать эту необходимость как рычаг, который поможет нам "продать" идею хорошего вопроса автору. Например:

"Если вы добавите в вопрос код программы или создадите простой пример на jsfiddle.com, мы быстрее разберемся в проблеме и поможем. В противном случае вы рискуете остаться без ответа на свой вопрос".

"Если вы объясните, для чего вам такая информация, нам будет легче посоветовать книгу или сайт. Сейчас информации очень мало, поэтому вам либо дадут бессмысленные ответы, либо модераторы закроют вопрос".

И т.п.

Comment: 200-300 раз многовато )))

Answer (score 12):

Надо интеллигентно попросить уточнить чего же хотел автор? Если автор молчит или продолжает в том же духе - закрыть вопрос или убить.

Comment: "или убить" - автора? Ну вопросу это явно не поможет )) Хотя с другой стороны других аналогичных вопросов будет уже меньше )

Comment: убить - значит удалить вопрос

Answer (score 4):

Автор темы смешал два разных вопроса:

1. Как поступать с раздражением при виде вопроса? (Источник которого может быть самым разным, вплоть до вкусового.)
2. Как поступать с вопросами, объективно засоряющими ноосферу? (Отвечено во всех мыслимых руководствах, решается за минуту в уме, не указаны важные параметры, патологическая лень и безмыслие автора, и т.п.)

По первому пункту: не встрявать без намерения сделать мир лучше. Если не нравится — пройти стороной.

По второму пункту: минусовать; в исправимых случах — указывать на возможности к улучшению; в неизлечимых — закрывать, не тратя нервов.

Comment: "Как поступать с вопросами, объективно засоряющими ноосферу?" - это уже вы придумали.

Answer (score 3):

Написать ответ в котором сообщить об ошибках, т.к. вдруг кто то из начинающих найдет этот вопрос и ему будет полезна информация как вопроса, так и указание на ошибки. А по поводу сути, которая "находится очень близко", её тоже можно просто огласить и всё. Понять и простить.