# Изменения раздела справки "Будьте дружелюбными"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, правила

Как результат [обсуждения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/535/), предлагаю внести изменения в раздел справочного центра "[Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)".

Результат. Добавили новый раздел в справочный центр: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-friendly.

---

#### Что делать, если вопрос вызывает злость?

На этом сайте нет места злости: *лучше не ответить на вопрос, нежели ответить на него агрессивно*. Действительно, некоторые вещи могут вызывать агрессию, но это не значит, что надо вымещать её здесь же - сайт несет *образовательную миссию*, и эта *образовательная миссия* простирается далеко за разбор конкретных примеров и разъяснения документации.

Если участник не нашел ответ в поисковике - возможно, он

- *не знает*, как правильно пользоваться поисковиком;
- *не может найти* решение, так как не знает, как правильно сформулировать запрос;
- *не понимает* представленную в выдаче информацию;
- *предполагает*, что не верно понял её;
- *не верит*, что может справиться c заданием.

Никто не становится специалистом за один день. Всем нам, на какой бы стадии обучения мы ни находились, нужна квалифицированная помощь. Зачастую, особенно для специалистов начального уровня, необходима помощь не только в объяснении решения, но и *мета-помощь*. Разъясняя, каким образом следует подходить к поиску решения проблемы, а не только приводя само решение, мы не просто делимся знаниями, мы помогаем новичку стать специалистом.

Таким образом, мы рекомендуем либо не писать ничего вообще, либо писать по делу: как улучшить свой вопрос, почему необходим акцент на тех или иных аспектах, какую информацию следует предоставить и т. д.

Первое, что вы можете сделать, почувствовав жгучее желание объяснить автору, на чем мир стоит - просто закрыть вкладку и пройти мимо. Альтернативный вариант - можно вдохнуть, выдохнуть, и максимально формально, подробно и отстраненно расписать автору, в чем его ошибки. Например:

> XXX, у вас отсутствует форматирование кода, в результате чего я не могу его прочитать за разумное время.
>   Пожалуйста, приведите его в порядок.
>   Забегая вперед - существует большая вероятность того, что вы не разобрались с асинхронными вызовами в javascript, возможно, вам просто необходимо прочитать [соответствующую статью](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) в документации еще раз.

Comment: Со специалистами еще небольшая путаница, пока не знаю, как переформулировать.

Comment: Я не вижу связи между оригинальным разделом ["Будьте дружелюбными"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) и рассуждениями о злости в этом вопросе. Солидарен с идеей, но следует использовать положительный язык [как в оригинале](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) (и в текущем русском варианте, который является простым близким к тексту переводом)

Comment: @jfs: там есть "Don't be a jerk". :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin: это секция *в конце* где *конкретные примеры* поведения, а не состояния ума приведены. [Вот можно почитать сколько труда необходимо, чтобы подобные тексты создавать](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/137096)

Comment: @jfs: ага, спасибо, хорошая ссылка.

Comment: @jfs Публикация пересекается в виду грубости по отношению к новичкам. На мой взгляд, это один из основных видов грубости в сообществе. Как я понимаю, вы предлагаете переписать текст, грубо говоря, с положительной стороны, верно?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: [текст уже написан](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Можно поиграться с переводом  *"If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does."*, но идея уже выражена кратко и ясно.

Comment: В любой группе людей существуют правила. В древности, еще до письменности, правила по большей части были негласные. Stack Overflow на русском - это в первую очередь сообщество. То есть у нас есть свои правила. С момента, когда новичок принимает решение стать частью сообщества, более осведомленные участники ("старички") показывают пример "правильного" поведения. В силу действующих ограничений интернет-сообществ, опытным пользователям приходится слишком часто повторяться во время обучения. От части, для оптимизации этого процесса был создан справочный центр.

Comment: Таким образом, если существует какое-либо поведение, которое не соответствует стандартам сообщества, на мой взгляд, стоит создать соответствующую запись в справочном центре. Руководствуясь этими соображениями, мне кажется, что стоит либо добавить дополнительный абзац в раздел “Будьте дружелюбными”, либо добавить в него ссылку на соответствующий вопрос на Мете. Это поможет в будущем сэкономить время при обучении новых участников правилам сообщества.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На первый взгяд, идея очень хорошая, но в таком объеме это TL;DR (т.е. «ниасилил»).

Предлагаемый текст по объему в полтора раза больше чем тот, что уже есть в рассматриваемом разделе справки. Если добавлять его — то как еще один абзац в две строки и два-три пункта списка. Кстати, все это уже в какой-то степени выражено единственным предложением, которое уже есть в тексте справки:

> *Если у вас не хватает времени на вежливость, лучше предоставить слово тому, у кого есть это время.*

А ещё хотелось бы знать, насколько распространена проблема, которую этот текст призван решить? Насколько я понимаю, она может быть сформулирована следующим образом:

> При виде некачественных вопросов, особенно задаваемых новичками на сайте и/или в профессии, другие участники часто испытывают гнев и выражают его вербально. Тем самым они ухудшают пользовательский опыт новых участников, препятствуя их профессиональному росту и интеграции в сообщество StackOverflow на русском. Кроме того, такое поведение не соответствует правилам участия, и существующие способы неэффективны в борьбе с ним.

Можно ли опубликовать какую-нибудь общую, анонимную статистику:

- Насколько часто первый вопрос пользователя получает негативную реакцию?
- Как часто используются тревоги типа «невежливый или оскорбительный»?

Comment: С публикацией есть два варианта: 1) в виде дополнительного раздела в справочном центре, 2) в виде публикации на Мете и ссылке из раздела справки на соответствующий вопрос. Официальной статистики грубости как таковой нет. Грубят в основном участники с большой репутацией, то есть если есть грубость, то много от небольшого количества пользователей.