# Отключение причины закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, домашки

История довольно старая. Было много обсуждений и споров по поводу этой причины закрытия:

- [Нужна ли нам причина закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9704/15479)
- [Что делать с вопросами по типу "нужно решить задачу, но сам я ничего не сделал"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9631/15479)
- [Причина "Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи" применяется не так, как задумывалась изначально](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6189/15479).

Из минусов существования этой причины закрытия:

- Закрываются хорошие вопросы. Если вопрос является "домашкой" - это ещё не означает, что вопрос плох. Он всё ещё может быть полезен сообществу.
- Закрытие с этой причиной некоторых авторов сбивает с толку.
- Такие вопросы после закрытия попадают в очередь, где требуется участие 5 человек для решения дальнейшей судьбы вопроса
- И т.д. Подробнее можно посмотреть в прошлых обсуждениях (ссылки выше).

### Что мы сейчас делаем?

1. Отключаем причину закрытия «учебные задания» для начала на один месяц.
2. Смотрим по ходу влияние этого решения (на другие очереди и т.п.).
3. Через месяц подводим итог. И уже смотрим, что делать дальше.

### Важное для закрывающих

1. Не нужно подгонять вопросы, которые раньше закрывались как "домашки" под другие причины закрытия. Оценивайте не намерение автора, а полезность для базы знаний. **За минусование вопросов у вас репутация не отнимается.**
2. Если вопрос плох/бесполезен - минусуйте. Участники с 10к репутации могут удалять такие заминусованные вопросы.
3. Но **не минусуйте** вопросы, которые просто простые и/или не показывают работу автора по его решению. Как уже обсуждалось ([раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/178988), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4883/178988), [три](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3892/178988) и ещё можно полно найти), такие вопросы могут быть полезны.
4. По возможности оставляйте комментарий автору, если думаете, что вопрос ещё можно спасти.

Comment: Чтобы голосовать за удаление 10К реповыми голосами, не обязательно минусовать. Проголосовать можно за любой вопрос, закрытый 2 или более дней назад, даже с положительным рейтингом.

Comment: @MSDN.'ReinstateMonica'Knight, речь про удаление открытых вопросов.

Comment: Пункт «что мы сейчас делаем» означает «мы так решили, и информируем вас», или «мы предлагаем так сделать, и ждём вашего фидбэка»?

Comment: @VladD обсуждение же уже было. Ссылки в самом начале. Сообщество решило, что причину нужно убрать. Вот убираем и смотрим, как это отразится на других причинах.

Comment: а как отключение одного из пунктов повлияло на «висящие» (в данный момент) в очереди вопросы? голоса за этот пункт пропали или остались?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin никак. Их всё ещё нужно просмотреть в очереди )=

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, тогда месячный проверочный срок, по-моему, будет маловат для оценки влияния данного пункта: насколько я помню, именно месяц вопрос может «провисеть» в очереди проверок (если не набрал достаточно голосов ни за, ни против закрытия). т.е. лишь спустя месяц в очереди гарантированно не будет вопросов с этой отключенной причиной.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin месяц взят так, чтоб оценить, был ли вред от того, что убрали причину закрытия. Если вреда не будет, то, думаю, можно будет продлить.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вроде за 4 дня должно пройти: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: *Если вопрос плох/бесполезен - минусуйте. Участники с 10к репутации могут удалять такие заминусованные вопросы* - что-то я или плохо смотрел, или... Я такой опции не вижу - в смысле, удаления вопроса...

Comment: @Harry да, она, похоже, только на закрытых вопросах появляется. Но ей все равно почти не пользуются. Большую часть заминусованного убивает бот через месяц.

Comment: Это довольно печально, учитывая, что [мой самый заплюсованный комментарий](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/cauwnu/when_you_get_help_on_stackoverflow_from_the/etbmen0/) на Реддите как раз о том, что у нас такая причина есть.  Про минусы очень не согласен.  Сто минусов будут намного неприятнее, чем закрытие вопроса.

Comment: @Ainar-G печально то, что многие несут дух этого заплюсованного комментария сюда, и начинают озвучивать его именно в таком виде. Причем это активно расползается - сначала начинают грубить в ответ на домашки, потом - в ответ на простые вопросы "да неужели так тяжело погуглить!". Потом - при виде средней сложности начинают писать "с таким вам на фриланс!". А в результате все сидят и грустят "что-то вопросов нет, сообщество умирает" :(

Comment: @PashaPash  Не вижу, как удаление причины уменьшает грубость.  Скорее наоборот: так бы удалили вопрос быстро, и не было бы причин для грубости.  ОП же по сути говорит там «минусуй», что явно более негативно.

Comment: @Ainar-G  Цель не "удалить вопрос быстро", а "спасти и ответить, если есть что спасать". У нас не так много вопросов. Лучше получить пару лишних вопросов-задач, на которых новички смогут репутацию набрать, чем сжечь их только из-за предполагаемой лени автора. То, что кто-то задал кривой вопрос - не причина грубить. Мне, например, не нравятся вопросы про склеивание SQL через + на PHP - но я же сдерживаюсь :)

Comment: @PashaPash  Ну так все однообразные вопросы про SQL-инъекции должны дубликатами быть, то есть опять же закрываться.

Comment: @Ainar-G тем не менее, ненависть к вопросам про SQL-инъекции довела минимум одного участника до годового бана :)

Comment: Печально, что ни в одном из приведенных обсуждений нет *даже попытки* составить список таких вопросов, скажем, за последний месяц. По списку  можно было бы лучше оценить ситуацию.

Comment: @defaultlocale примеры хороших вопросов закрытых как домашки были, вот только не помню, в каком из обсуждений.

Comment: Я думаю, до годового бана Ипатьева довела неумелая модерация, а не плохие вопросы.

Comment: @VladD на enSO бан был тоже из-за "плохой модерации"?

Comment: @Suvitruf: Я не могу говорить о ситуации на en.SO, я с ней незнаком. Однако же о том, что модерация на ru.SO была ужасна, я знаю не понаслышке. Вы можете спросить об этом у версии себя до избрания модератором, уверен, много интересного узнаете.

Comment: @Harry, вопрос должен быть достаточно старым. Попробуй поискать по дате и отрицательному рейтингу.

Comment: @VladD как эти события связаны с Ипатьевым?

Comment: Хорошо, тогда возникает локальный (лично для меня) вопрос: со смертью метки `unity3d` можно просто смириться и перебираться на enSO? На данный момент она перенасыщена вопросами по типу: "я вот тут хочу сделать *штуку*, но не знаю, как это сделать, а сделайте за меня тогда". По дз такой вопрос не закроешь, минусовать? На этой метке раньше, может быть, регулярно сидело 2-3 активных человека, сегодня еще меньше. Про дубликаты и "не ответы" в ответах я даже не говорю, моего голоса за закрытие банально не хватает, я могу прямо список "устаревших" или отклоненных тревог на такие вопросы привести.

Comment: И все вышесказанное ведет экспоненциальному росту числа действительно бесполезных и, зачастую, дублирующих вопросов, на которые даже иногда дают ответы без всяких тревог на дубликат, чем еще больше сподвигают задавать подобные бесполезные вопросы.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker а как отключение причины закрытия влияет на количество интересных вам вопросов? Что с причиной, что без неё количество вопросов по [tag:unity3d] не шибко большое.

Comment: Чем вопрос "А как мне сферу по полу покатать?" не является учебным? Хорошо, допустим, он не совсем "учебный", по какому признаку его закрывать? Минусовать? И я, кстати, нигде не говорил про "интересные мне" вопросы, я сказал, что, **к примеру**, знакомая мне метка просто умерла под наплывом плохих вопросов, а тут еще и один из инструментов отключают, на что я и спросил: "а что лично мне тогда делать, если вместе со мной и 5 человек на метке для голосования и минусования не найдется?".

Comment: @RiotBr3aker теперь понял. Ну да, вопрос учебный. С этим никто не спорит. Но ведь вопрос не плохой. На него многие ищут ответ. Следовательно, он для базы был бы полезен.

Comment: Он был полезен первый раз, может быть, второй **такой же** вопрос с другой формулировкой был тоже полезен, но когда вся метка завалена такими вопросами - это уже, имхо, плохо. Опять же, проблема в том, что с этим никто не борется, пары активных человек просто не хватает. А комьюнити не растет из-за того, что новички получают ответ на свой базовый вопрос и уходят восвояси, ну может они ещё вернутся пару раз, чтобы задать ещё какой-нибудь базовый вопрос. На чужие базовые вопросы такие пользователи не отвечают.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker если появляется похожий вопрос, но там, скажем, вместо сферы фигурирует куб, то нужно как дубль закрывать)

Comment: Вот буквально на самой свежей странице тревог нашел 4 "устаревших" тревоги вопросов по метке `unity3d`. Закрыты ли они? Нет. Кто-то дал на них ответ? Нет. Одна из них - дубликат, где человек дважды задал один и тот же вопрос с разницей в 5! часов. На него, естественно, тоже никто не ответил. Одна из моих свежих тревог вообще отклонена, но вопрос почему-то закрыт по той же причине, что и моя тревога. В итоге все это привело к негативному опыту использования тревог в конкретной метке. Есть ли желание кидать тревоги, которые либо устареют, либо их отклонят по неведомой причине? Да не особо :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я просмотрел часть тревог ваших. "Не является" ответом не следует использовать для плохих ответов. А вопросы "не по теме" следует закрывать, а не флагать. Тревоги - это, по существу, крайняя мера. Большую часть вещей по контенту можно разрулить без участия модераторов.

Comment: "Не является ответом" я уже не использую, так, дал слабину недавно :) Вопросы не по теме я и закрываю, однако я это делаю обычно один, соответственно, через какое-то время голосовка сбрасывается.

Comment: P.S. На самом деле это уже разговоры не по теме, так что предлагаю прекратить сие обсуждение, но было приятно пообщаться :D

Comment: @Suvitruf: Самое прямое. Если единственное средство модерации — бан, то не удивительно, что многие участники, имеющие свою точку зрения на то, что должно быть на сайте, попадают в бан. Удивительно, если они после этого возвращаются.

Comment: @VladD спросите Ипатьева, что он думает про "плохих модераторов". Я не понимаю, почему вы от его имени пишете.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Что вы, я пишу всегда исключительно от своего имени. Разве я где-то ссылался на мнение Ипатьева? И я писал не о плохих модераторах, а о плохой модерации, это, согласитесь, разные вещи (особенно в свете CoC).

Comment: @RiotBr3aker эту причину вводили для борьбы с домашними заданиями, а не с базовыми вопросами. ДЗ - это когда человеку говорят "катай сферу", а он, вместо того, чтобы разобраться и попробовать покатать сам, идет на SO, копипастит задание и пишет "нужно сдать завтра". А "я учу Unity, хочу покатать сферу, не знаю как, помогите" - это не дз. Это просто плохо оформленный вопрос от новичка. Таких полно по любой метке, и именно закрытие таких вопросов как "домашки" - это то самое "злоупотребление".

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я понимаю, что хочется чтобы по метке были только интересные сложные вопросы - но не получится. Простых, тривиальных и дубликатов всегда будет много, и больше чем сложных и интересных. И на ruSO, и на enSO. У нас даже есть отдельная тема про это на мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/616/

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, любой вопрос, на который вы не знаете ответа — учебный для вас => он должен быть закрыт => смысла задавать его нет } нет смысла задавать любой вопрос. Так, следуя вашей логике?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я выше привел конкретный пример вопросов и конкретную проблему флуда вопросами, которые решаются чтением 1го предложения документации или гугления в этом же стэке. Я даже объяснил, почему лично я не могу с этим ничего поделать: метка скорее  мертва, чем жива, постоянных людей на ней практически нет -> комьюнити самостоятельно отфильтровать контент не может, а админов на каждую метку не напасешься.

Comment: @АндрейNOP да и насчет этого `любой вопрос, на который вы не знаете ответа — учебный для вас` абсолютно не согласен. Учеба - вещь медитативная, если человек действительно учился и столкнулся с непонятной проблемой - классный повод спросить здесь, спору нет. Но, повторюсь, на конкретной метке `unity3d` в большинстве случаев случается так: `ничего не учил, 5 минут назад установил юнити, а как сделать вот это`, либо `я тут придумал игру, а как реализовать вот такую фичу`, причем без шуток и преувеличений припоминаю вопрос, когда человек прямым текстом просил реализовать за него кусок игры.

Comment: @PashaPash  Ещё одна проблема: недовольные домашками люди будут минусовать людей, отвечающих на вопросы-домашки, чтобы стимулировать их не отвечать.

Comment: @Ainar-G сейчас на домашки тоже успевают отвечать (закрывают же не мгновенно), и на ответах чаще или нейтральная оценка, или вообще плюсы.

Comment: Многие такие "вопросы" даже вопросительного знака не содержат. Да и некуда его там воткнуть. "Вот задание", "Сделать", "Желательно побыстрее".

Comment: @extrn ну так это и не вопросы вовсе. минус, максимум - "непонятна суть вопроса", и все. Бесполезно тратить на них время, взывать к совести автора и уговаривать его "постараться".

Comment: Я полностью согласен с тем,  что  если если вопрос является "домашкой" - это ещё не означает, что вопрос плох     И если частники с 10к репутации могут удалять  заминусованные вопросы, то  за  отключения этой опции вообше, Но есть одна проблема:  очень многие  будут обращаться сюда  с целью  решения своих заданий нахаляво. Это принесет большой вред учебному процессу  учебных заведений

Comment: Иногда вопрос вовсе не является вопросом, а  является дерзким заказом выпонения задания, типа: " Требуется   ..." .  В таких случаях так и хочется не только закрыть вопрос, но и показать "желтую карточку ", чтобы впредь хотябы проявляли уважение к сайту и к его участникам... Вопрос: "как быть?... " все еще в силе.

Comment: Уже 11 число.  Может, пора возвращать причину на место?

Comment: @Ainar-G зачем?

Comment: Многие (Harry, Akina, Streletz, я) уже высказали причины в комментариях и ответах.  Отсутствие этой причины закрытия увеличивает негатив и никак не влияет на позитив.

Comment: Ну, план ведь был отключить только на месяц, а потом подвести итоги. Что на счет итогов? :) Было бы интересно узнать, как это повлияло на количество закрытых/заминусованных вопросов и т.п.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat жду Николая. Он должен необходимые запросы отгрузить, чтобы ответить на эти вопросы.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Если составление итогов затягивается, я бы вернул причину на место. Все-таки в посте написали, что ее уберут только на месяц.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я, всё же, хочу сначала метрики посмотреть. Николай куда-то пропал, поэтому я Шогу написал. Надеюсь, он с этим поможет.

Comment: Уже 11 число второго месяца прошло.  Есть ли информация по метрикам?  По тому, что я вижу, поток домашних заданий и минусов им всё ещё большой.

Comment: @Ainar-G извиняюсь. Только сейчас [руки дошли](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10013/15479). Думал, что Николай опубликует (:

Answer (score 24):

Знаете... а может, хватит этого эксперимента? Или верните пункт про "учебные вопросы", или, еще лучше - добавьте пункт о закрытии

> Потому что просто должно быть стыдно требовать выполнить за вас такое простое задание...

Последняя капля сегодня [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1046773/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80). Приходится либо писать причину ("Другое"), либо прикручивать не совсем подходящую...

Comment: Уровень простоты задания у всех людей разный. Это конечно не тензорное счисление, но по факту вы хотели наказать за лень: ну так для этого не обязательно закрывать вопрос, достаточно один клик сделать на downvote.

Comment: Так же я считаю, что правильная причина закрытия также находится на расстоянии пары кликов: "что конкретно вам непонятно в этом задании" ака "непонятна суть вопроса Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему". Представьте, что вопрос был бы по какой-то сложной теме, которая для ЗНАЮЩЕГО ОТВЕТ точно также декомпозируется на несколько менее сложных. И в простой и в сложной теме, которая делится на отдельные "кирпичики" должно быть уточнение "какую именно часть вопроса вы не понимаете?" и ответ давать надо на неё.

Comment: Простой вопрос не значит плохой. При всей своей простоте он может быть полезен базе знаний, раз люди его задают.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, его наверняка зададут ещё не один раз, т.к.авторы таких вопросов не желают даже гуглить. Они желают только готовое решение. В прочем, своё мнение относительно этого я высказывал уже неоднократно.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Если часто будут задавать вопрос "как вычислить 2*2" - то он полезен базе знаний? На всякий случай - этот мой вопрос полезным не считаю :)

Comment: @AK Да если бы хотя бы вопрос не был сформулирован в духе задания из учебника! Готов спорить - напиши такую функцию - тут же пошло бы "она не компилируется" - просто потому что человек даже не подумал бы вставить ее в программу. Сколько раз, простите неполиткорректность, ленивые глупцы в ответ на ответ пишут "оно не компилируется" просто потому, что нужно добавить нужный инклуд! Да напиши "какие есть способы по координатам трех вершин треугольника определить его площадь" - и задача превращается в уже реально интересный вопрос... А не "написать функцию". Так и представляется капо с плеткой...

Comment: @Harry я всегда был против "домашек". И не люблю оказывать медвежью услугу. С другой стороны, компания форсирует "базу знаний", где "на любой вопрос найдётся ответ". У меня позиция во всём этом не однозначная. Могу лишь посоветовать [этот вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/535/15479) посмотреть.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Да там явный дубликат. Вечно наши топы по С++ все подряд закрывают с левой причиной. Пожалуйста, переоткройте и закройте дубликатом на тот вопрос, который я скинул в комментариях.

Comment: @MSDN.'ReinstateMonica'Knight что забавно, там и ответ от Harry есть (:

Comment: @Streletz это применимо к любому простому вопросу. Знаете, сколько у нас закрыто дубликатов про php-ную "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"? так что теперь, php запретить?

Comment: @Harry не все так однозначно - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572510 - вопрос, по сути, "как вычислить 2*2". Три голоса за, два ответа - +6 и +8.

Comment: @PashaPash, речь здесь не о простых вопросах как таковых. А, о том, что многие не могут или не хотят даже гуглом воспользоваться. В прочем, одинаковые вопросы можно с чистой совестью закрыть как дубликат.

Comment: @PashaPash Есть разница между "почему" (подразумевает - хочу знать) и "сделайте" (подразумевает - хочу сдать).

Comment: @Streletz на любой вопрос по любой распространенной технологии есть ответ в гугле. Кроме домашних заданий.

Comment: @Harry так суть изменений как раз в том, чтобы [использовать для таких "сделайте" правильный и эффективный инструмент - минуса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9707/177221). До изменений такие вопросы закрывали голосами 5 человек, но при этом на вопрос редко прилетало больше 1-2 минусов. Нет смысла ради "сделайте за меня" собирать каждый раз пятерых 3000+ участников.

Comment: @PashaPash, так и на них есть ответы, т.к. в домашках дают простейшие вещи. Конечно, если автора сам пытается разобраться и привёл код своих попыток решить задачу самостоятельно, вопросов нет. Хотя это всё равно не повод плодить дубликаты. А, если вопрос сводится к очередному "сделайте за меня" или "переведите задачку в код", толку от него?..

Comment: @Harry При этом совсем типовая домашка (копипаста из учебника) 100% попадает под "непонятна суть вопроса". Писать таким авторам "должно быть стыдно требовать выполнить за вас такое простое задание" - абсолютно бесмысленно. Как будто им до этого было непонятно, что дз нужно делать самостоятельно.

Comment: @Streletz И как из этого следует, что в случае домашки мы должны не просто заминусовать автора, чтобы он ушел и больше не вернулся, но еще и собрать пятерых участников с 3000+ репутации, чтобы они всесторонне рассмотрели копипасту из учебника и "потребовали у автора правки вопроса"? Почему вас не устраивает просто минусование? Почему вы настаиваете, что нужно использовать именно механизм "требования правки", причем к тем вопросам, где очевидно, что правки не будет?

Comment: @PashaPash Меня не устраивает просто минусование именно потому, что закрытие вопроса требует уже проверенных участников, с указанием обоснования - а минуса у нас часто лепят просто из личных отношений...

Comment: @Harry так закрытие домашек - это и есть закрытие *исключительно из личного отношения*. Единственная разница между "домашкой" и обычным вопросом - ваше личное отношение к мотивации автора (учусь vs сделайте за меня), а не само содержимое вопроса. Я предлагаю не лепить голоса за закрытие и не тратить время других участников из личных отношений.

Comment: Да, но тут надо хотя бы *мотивировать* свое решение. Минусы обычно ставятся молча...

Comment: @Harry так в случае "домашки" не нужно ничего мотивировать. Те, кто копипастит домашку из учебников, и так знают, что это плохо. От того, что вы им еще раз это скажете - ничего не поменяется. Не надо тратить время других участников на лентяев. Закрытие таких вопросов не дает вообще никакого эффекта. Их как была пара штук в день (с сезонными пиками) до введения причины, так и осталась. Некоторые получали ответы и до введения причины, и после. Причину отменили - и что-то не видно завала сайта домашками. Суть изменений - убирать такие вопросы  быстро и дешево, с автобаном задающего.

Comment: @Harry на примере из вашего ответа - закрыли бы "Написать функцию,принимающих координаты вершин треугольника на плоскости и возвращающую его площадь" с причиной "домашки". Какой реально профит был бы от потраченного времени пятерых участников? Незарегистрированный участник Алексей стал бы решать ДЗ самостоятельно?

Comment: @PashaPash А какой профит от потраченного времени на минуса? Какой, кстати, профит от ваших комментариев здесь? :)

Comment: @Harry минусы уводят вопрос с ленты и автобанят аккаунт. От моих комментариев тут прямой профит - меньше хороших вопросов закроют только за то, что автор ленивый, больше времени у проверяющих будет для помощи тем, кому реально нужно помочь "закрытием", будет больше качественного контента, будет веселее тут сидеть :)

Comment: Не знаю, что эксперимент покажет в цифрах (впрочем, статистика - враньё), но я лично для себя могу чётко сказать одно. Раньше,  даже голосуя за закрытие, все более-менее снисходительно относились к таким вопросам, едко-саркастические комментарии были достаточно редки. Последние же недели две (после того, как стало понятно, что "минусуй не минусуй - всё равно ... не удаляется") это - норма, причём список тех, кто не очень терпимо высказывается, явно расширяется. То есть и бездельникам лучше не стало (всё равно не отвечают), и постоянных участников отсутствие этой причины явно раздражает.

Comment: @Akina Именно...

Answer (score 22):

Закрытие "студенческих" вопросов с формулировкой

> Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что
>   вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.
>   Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас
>   трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы
>   написали, пытаясь решить задачу

имеет ряд преимуществ.

- Даёт автору чёткое объяснение отрицательной реакции на его вопрос;
- На закрытый вопрос невозможно ответить. Что создаёт препятствия не только для медвежьих услуг, но и для потакания авторам подобных вопросов (в том числе в погоне за репутацией).

Другое дело, что в данный момент вопрос просто так нельзя закрыть. Для этого нужно 5 голосов участников с достаточно высокой репутацией. А, сколько таких участников и сколько из них принимает участие в модерации (я про голоса за закрытие и разбор очередей)?

Кроме того, закрытие не мешает автору и дальше задавать вопросы. Конечно, при определённом количестве "плохих" вопросов можно получить бан. Только как правило большинство учёток со "студенческими" вопросами используется как одноразовые и их обладателям это не наносит серьёзного ущерба.

> Оценивайте не намерение автора, а полезность для базы знаний.

В том то и дело, что полезность подобных вопросов для базы знаний нулевая. Единственный человек, которому такой вопрос поможет, это его автор и то условно.

ИМХО, будет ли специальная причина закрытия для "домашек" или нет, подобные вопросы всё равно будут неминуемо появляться. Просто без неё сообществу будет несколько сложнее выразить своё отношение к ним и сайт будет в большей степени засоряться некачественными вопросами.

Comment: В очереди стабильно 500+ вопросов, так что, мало там активистов (:

Comment: Вот и я об этом. Тем более, что, если не изменяет память, количество проверок в день ограничено.

Comment: 20 проверок в день.

Comment: Вот-вот. Поэтому и копится очередь.

Comment: Там ещё проблема в том, что если не уверен, то нажимаешь "Пропустить". Т.е, в итоге людей нужно больше, чем 5, т.к. часть участников скипает неоднозначные вопросы.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica по своему опыту могу сказать, что судить о причинах закрытия трудно, данная платформа просто не дает ресурсов для обучения. Да и на практике учиться трудновато, ошибся - получаешь по рукам, сделал все хорошо - система тебе не говорит даже условное "спасибо". И я не говорю про отдачу за модерацию, понятное дело, что это добровольные начала.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker да, SO - это не форум и т.п, где присутствует общение. SO - это просто голая база знаний, где комментарии и т.п. считаются лишними.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica общение - это ладно, я про автоматическое "спасибо за модерацию, ([x] из [n]) ваших недавних голосов принесли пользу сообществу" от системы.

Comment: "Единственный человек, которому такой вопрос поможет, это его автор и то условно." - вы описали примерно 99% всех вопросов на SO. Так что ж теперь, сайт закрывать? :)

Comment: @PashaPash Не согласен. Мне встречалось очень много вопросов которые мне лично помогли.